# how do you get to this result?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question of how to solve this

$$B = \{x ∈ \mathbb{Z} : -2^x \leq 1\}$$

this according to a friend of mine should be $\{0, 1, 2, ... , \infty\}$

but how he gets to this is how I dont understand, if someone can help me understand this it would be great

Thank you, I dont know what the name of this is in English so I wrote something, feel free to edit

Comment: $(-2)^x$ or $-(2^x)$ ?

Comment: no paranthesis on the question

Comment: Thus, $-2^x$ is *negative*, because $2^x$ is always positive for $x \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Your friend is wrong: the answer is $\Bbb Z$, so: one $\infty$ too much and too few negative integers.

Comment: You friend would be right for $2^{-x}$.

Comment: thank you, but I dont quite understand how you know its Z, but Z is also negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

We have $-2^x \le 1$  iff $2^x \ge -1$

But always $2^x >0$, hence $B= \mathbb Z$

Comment: thanks, but then my friend is incorrect because he had a 0 in his answer? and second of all, do you confirm B=Z by checking the 2^x>0 or by testing x values? and if so, why is no negative numbers in the sequence?